# error after including as3 "expecting rightbrace before public"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, import

I have this error after using include in as3:

> `1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before
>   public.   game.as /game   line 9`

the source code for Main is:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    include "setings\resolution.as";


    public class game extends Sprite
    {
        public function game()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and the resolution.as is empty. any solution/explication?

Thanks

Comment: `setings\resolution.as` is apparently malformed. That's all we can say without seeing it. Maybe it's missing a closing `}`?

Comment: incidentally, `include` isn't a very action-script-ey way to do things (in fact, used like this, I don't think it would be recommended in any language). You'd probably be better off using inheritance.

Comment: setings\resolution.as is empty

Comment: well the other options are: you shouldn't have a `;` after the include line, and `\ ` is an escape character (use `/` or `\\ ` instead)

Comment: Dave, setings\resolution.as is empty. i want to add this later in it, to change resolution only changing that file 
'[SWF(width="1280", height="800", backgroundColor="#000000", frameRate="30")]'

Comment: `\r` in a string is the escape sequence for carriage return. Always use / in file paths in ActionScript, also on Windows systems.

Comment: solved: i had to make it MovieClip instead of Sprite! how I set this solved and how do i put a solution? my first time on stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/`, not `\`.  This cleared the error on my machine.